# Installing dependancies

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, open-source

I am trying to build some packages from source and I get messages that say I need the following:

-glib2 (*DONE*) (apt-get install glib-2.6)

-directfb

-libpng

-m4 (*TRIED*) I got this installed but still get a message that it is missing.

- libtool.m4 not found
- glib-gettext.m4 not found
- pkg.m4 not found

> ***Error***: some autoconf macros required to build Package
>   were not found in your aclocal path, or some forbidden
>   macros were found. Perhaps you need to adjust your
>   ACLOCAL_FLAGS?

Searching google:
directfb and libpng I am just not finding clear install instructions. As for m4 how can I check that I have installed it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say which image/distribution you are using, tho it appears to be some kind of debian linux (perhaps raspbian?).

Generally linux distro packages have a separate associated "development" package which contains the bits you need when compiling with them, since these are not required for normal use.  For debian they are labelled with "-dev", eg:

```
> apt-cache search directfb | grep dev
libdirectfb-dev - direct frame buffer graphics library - development files
```

If you don't have the dev package installed, you won't be able to build against the library.  `m4` won't have one, but you should install the base libtool package and also the glib *dev* package.  BTW, don't confuse glibc (notice the c) with glib.

Providing a link to the software you are trying to compile might help too.

Comment: Sorry yes this is raspbian... I do plan to try this on Arch as soon as I get it working here. http://alioth.debian.org/projects/splashy/

Comment: apt-cache search glib | grep dev overfills the screen so that I can not find the name of the package I want.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get build-dep [x]

Use that if you are i.e. wanting to build a slightly newer version of a package, which has an older version already in the repo. Chances are they wont have changed too much.