# Where can I get a COMPLETE libfcgi install for Pi 3B

Tags: raspbian, gcc

I used apt-get to install the fastcgi package recently (sudo apt-get install libfcgi) and my Pi3B duly chuckled away then announced that it hwas finished.
BUT when I tried to compile the backend to lighttpd that I am writing in C, I was told 'cannot find fcgi_stdio.h'. Now I have been writing this backend on a desktop Linux box and I installed libfcgi from the sources and I know that these include files should have also been installed by apt-get.
    {
        fcgi_config.h
        fcgi_stdio.h
        fcgiapp.h
        fcgimisc.h
        fcgio.h
        fcgios.h
    {

On checking for the libraries, I found that only the shared library had been installed - without its link table. The static library was also not installed.
The list of libraries installed should look like:

```
{
    libfcgi.a
    libfcgi.la*
    libfcgi.so -> libfcgi.so.0.0.0*
    libfcgi.so.0 -> libfcgi.so.0.0.0*
    libfcgi.so.0.0.0*
}
```

Can somebody please point me to a COMPLETE libfcgi package for the Raspberry Pi 3?

And before someone tells me that I should get the source and compile it on the Pi, I've tried that and it opens an even bigger can of smelly worms.
./configure doesn't complete successfully, make complains that @LIBTOOL@ is missing, gcc's man pages are absent - I could go on and on.
Peter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get Bluetooth/Bluetooth.h for Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/where-to-get-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-for-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in part a duplicate of these questions:

- [compilation errors : gtk+-2.0 gthread-2.0 not found](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/12416/5538)
- [Installing dependancies](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/5246/5538)

Although since `apt` has a new, simplified, slightly snazzier interface I'll use the new version here and make the common point more clear.

> I know that these include files should have also been installed by apt-get

Really? Why?

Library packages are usually installed as dependencies of other binaries.  To serve at runtime, the include/header files (i.e., `.h` files) are not required, so these are kept in a separate `-dev` package (there may be other non-essential odds and ends as well, and possibly debugging symbols are in yet another package, but `gdb` should explain this to you when you need them).

So to find it, a general approach might be:

```
apt search libfcgi | grep -B 2 dev
```

The `-B 2` here includes the two previous lines of the search hit, since the output of `apt search` (vs. the older style `apt-cache search`) is is split across several lines and the description will be on one of its own preceded by the package name.  In this case it's actually unnecessary since we're looking for a hit on part of the package name (`dev`) and so the output ends up as:

```
Sorting...
Full Text Search...
libfcgi-dev/stable 2.4.0-8.3 armhf
```

So the headers can probably be installed via `apt install libfcgi-dev`.  Likely in this case so are the static archives (see below).

Another way of doing this, which provides more confirmation, is to `apt install apt-file`, then e.g.:

```
> apt-file search fcgi_config.h
libfcgi-dev: /usr/include/fcgi_config.h
```

Beware while this one works, it is dependent on the package database info being correct, which is sometimes not the case on Raspbian -- presumably it happens when lib packages must be split in odd ways but there is not the resources people wise to manage them all properly.  There are a few examples of this coming up.

> I should get the source and compile it on the Pi

This is rarely necessary and should only be done as a last resort or because you need a particular version of something which is unavailable.  In that case you install to `/usr/local` and subsequently run `ldconfig` for libraries so the linker will index them.

> make complains that @LIBTOOL@ is missing

Solving this involves the same general approach...

```
apt search libtool
```

There are various hits but hint, it's just `libtool`.  There should be some meta package that's good for that and various other things such as "build-essential" but I am not sure what it is called (although a quick search for "linux debian apt install build essential" confirms that it is; remember, Raspbian is essentially Debian but Debian is much more extensively documented, so searching that way will lead to better results; you'll likely also get Ubuntu hits but those are very often applicable as well, particularly when it comes to package names).

> gcc's man pages are absent

That's an odd one but I notice it's true on Raspbian even when gcc is installed.  `apt search gcc | grep doc` turns up various `doc` packages.

Looking in `/usr/share/man`, you can see man pages on Raspbian are installed in gzipped form with a section number suffix, e.g., `foobar.3.gz`.  The basename is the name of the man page; from the descriptions of man page sections in `man man` section 1 ("Executable programs or shell commands") is a good guess, but `apt-file search gcc.1.gz` implies some odd things, one of which is that the `gcc` package includes a `c89-gcc` and `c99-gcc` man page -- but these are just short stubs.

Sometimes [the online Debian search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) works better, and trying `gcc.1.gz` via *Search the contents of packages* does claim it's in `gcc-doc`, except here we have a discrepancy -- there is no such package in Raspbian.  They've done something odd again.  I believe this is consequent of the fact that the architecture doesn't correspond to any of the Debian ARM branches (including `armhf` -- don't get confused by this), and the core C library and compiler are very specifically for ARM1176JZ(F)-S.

But there is a `gcc-4.9-doc`, and subsequent to `apt install gcc-4.9-doc` (a zany 14 MB...), you'll have a `man gcc`.  It may actually be in the dependency, `gcc-doc-base` but a further likely Raspbian specific flub is that `dpkg -L` doesn't show it in either one (or anything that would add up to 14 MB).  Go figure.  This is probably also why `apt-file` doesn't find it properly.

> Can somebody please point me to a COMPLETE libfcgi package for the Raspberry Pi 3?

The online Debian search claims it is in the `-dev` package. `apt-file search` on Raspbian doesn't find it, but as we've seen, it is imperfect.  Since you're installing the dev package anyway, check to see if it's in `/usr/lib` subsequently:

```
find /usr/lib -name libfcgi.a
```

If it's not, it has been left out and presumably either you make do with the `.so` or else build from source.

Comment: Thank you. The -dev search found what I needed to compile my backend. Now I'm struggling with lighttpd's ratty treatment of paths in its config but I'm used to that.